# TYPO3, after installing the Icon Picker (bw_icons) extension, in RTE the Box option is inactive

Tags: bootstrap-4, icons, typo3-11.x

I'm using TYPO3 v11.5, Bootstrap package, Icon Picker (bw_icons). After installing the Icon Picker (bw_icons) extension, in the backend panel, field [bodytext] the Box option is inactive.

[Screenshot from the backend panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdZaF.png)

If I remove the IconPicker.yaml file from the import in Default.yaml, then the option Box becomes active. But then there is no option to insert an icon.

Thank you very much for your answers.

*# typo3conf/ext/my_site_package/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml*

```
imports:        
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
    - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" } 
    - { resource: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Configuration/RTE/Default.yaml" } 
    - { resource: "EXT:bw_icons/Configuration/RTE/IconPicker.yaml" }    

editor:
    config:                
        - { contentsCss: "EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Public/Css/bootstrap4-rte.min.css" }
        - { contentsCss: "EXT:bw_icons/Resources/Public/Css/Rte.css" }

    toolbar:
        - { name: 'icon', items: [IconPicker] }
```